# Extending function syntax explanation

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I found js function that is called when onkeypress event of textBox fires. I'am asking if some one could explain its syntax.

```
function isDecimalKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46) return false;
  return true;
}
```

I'm not certain what this `var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode` bit of code means but I want to extend this function so it will also check if number is in allowed range that is max value 999.9 min value 0.0. number can have only 1 decimal place so it cant be 1.123.

Suming up: Value can have maximum 5 characters including "." for decimals, and maximum 1 decimal place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just the ternary operator which basically says

```
(is this expression true) ? -> YES DO THIS : NOPE, ITS NOT DO THAT INSTEAD
```

In this instance, you could easily replace the line by just using logical OR

```
var charCode = evt.which || event.keyCode;
```

Basically this is the same check. If `evt.which` has any truthy value the interpreter will ignore the right side expression. If the first expression evaluates to `false`, we use the rightside expression regardless what it contains.

Comment: So it means if `evt.which` is null or NaN then `charCode = event.keyCode`?

Comment: Thank you very much for clear explanation then, have nice day :)